# Error with 2sxc Blog: does not contain a definition for 'LinkToPageNumber'

Tags: 2sxc

We have the 2sxc AppBlog module in place and it has been working for months.  Suddenly, I get contacted from the client that it's not working.  When the page loads, the error is '`Error rendering template`.'  In the logs, the full exception is:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_Blog_App__library_cshtml' does not contain a definition for 'LinkToPageNumber'
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 )
at ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_Blog_App__pager_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Webs\TAD\Portals\0\2sxc\Blog App\_pager.cshtml:line 18
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass7.&lt;RenderPageCore&gt;b__6(TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result)
at ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_Blog_App__1_Main_blog_view_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Webs\TAD\Portals\0\2sxc\Blog App\_1 Main blog view.cshtml:line 23
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 65
at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\2Sexy Content Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 75
at ToSic.SexyContent.Engines.EngineBase.Render() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 89
at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.Render() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\SxcInstance.cs:line 200
```

Any ideas what's up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, through more digging, I was able to fix the issue myself.  The code in the `_pager.cshtml` file was calling `lib.LinkToPageNumber`.  lib was referenced to another .cshtml file, but LinkToPageNumber was a method in the _pager.cshtml file itself.  All I had to do was remove `lib.` in front of the several instances of `LinkToPageNumber`, and all was well.

This error only showed up when our blog went past 1 page, and that's why it was working fine up until that point.

Comment: it's fixed in newer versions of the blog BTW. Another note: please mark this question as answered.